# HTML to OOXML in TemplateProcessor

Tags: phpword

I'm using the `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor` to parse Docx files, but I need to inject HTML into these. Obviously I can't put the HTML directly into that, so I need to convert it to OOXML.

`\PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord` has the option to: `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);`, which injects the converted OOXML into the document, but this doesn't work with the `TemplateProcessor`.

How can I convert the HTML to OOXML when using the `TemplateProcessor`? I've looked through the code, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

Use the library https://github.com/rkorebrits/HTMLtoOpenXML

For install `composer require rkorebrits/htmltoopenxml`

If use laravel then used:

`$parser = new \HTMLtoOpenXML\Parser();
$ooXml = $parser->fromHTML($html);`

the difference is the backslash `\HTMLtoOpenXML\Parser();`, if you use it with any other framework you can remove the `\` before `HTMLtoOpenXML\Parser();`

Then to add the html to our template we do this:

`$templateWord = new TemplateProcessor($template);
$templateWord->setValue('dataHTML', $ooXml);`

Regards

Comment: That is my own library :-) Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

It only works for me when I set the Outputescaping to false

```
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(false);
```

And before I save the file I set it to true again, this way my word doc isn't corrupted :)

```
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);
```